# Is there a template tag I can use to link to the archive page corresponding to the month that a post was published on?

Tags: theme-development, templates, archives, template-tags

For example, if the post was published on may 5th 2011, then clicking on "May 5th, 2011" would show all posts published in May 2011. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight from the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link)

```
<?php $arc_year = get_the_time('Y'); ?>
<?php $arc_month = get_the_time('m'); ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_month_link($arc_year, $arc_month); ?>">archive for <?php the_time('F Y'); ?></a>
```

Comment: @trusktr no problem, good luck